# Reshaping data into a more useful form

Tags: list-manipulation

Below is a sample of some data that I have imported in the format of comma separated values.

```
data =

{{"1993-10-29","AAV",0.7},{"1993-11-30","AAV",0.47}, 
{"1993-12-31","AAV",0.55},{"1994-01-31","AAV",0.5}, 
{"1994-02-28","AAV",0.46},{"1994-03-31","AAV",0.35},
{"1994-04-29","AAV",0.57},{"1993-10-29","ABX",35.75}, 
{"1993-11-30","ABX",35.},{"1993-12-31","ABX",37.625}, 
{"1993-12-31","ABX",37.625},{"1994-01-31","ABX",36.875}, 
{"1994-02-28","ABX",33.875},{"1994-03-31","ABX",34.875}, 
{"1994-04-29","ABX",31.875}}
```

My goal is to create a neat table looking like the one below.

[image]

How do I get started?

Comment: Perhaps start here: [How to: Work with lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithLists.html). Some relevant commands would be e.g. [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [TableForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html).

Comment: I cannot visualize how you want the final result to look. Can you edit your question and add a diagram showing the result you expect.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
headings = {
{Item["Date", Frame -> {True, True}], 
Item["AAV", Frame -> {True, False}], 
Item["ABX", Frame -> {True, False}]}
};

Grid[Join[headings, (Flatten /@ GatherBy[data, First])[[All, {1, 3, 6}]]], 
Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All, Spacings -> {3, 1}, FrameStyle -> Orange]
```

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    Grid[Drop[Map[Prepend[#, ""] &, Transpose[data]], {2}], 
 ItemStyle -> {FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 12}, Dividers -> All, 
 ItemSize -> {6, 2}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 Background -> {None, {{LightBlue, LightOrange}}, 1 -> Yellow}]
```

with the effect:

[image]

Try to play with the parameters. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was not clear enough. I edited it and added a few information.

Answer (score 2):

With `Association` and `Dataset`:

```
dset = GroupBy[data, First -> Rest, Association @* MapApply[Rule]];

opts = {
   HeaderBackground -> GrayLevel[0.95],
   Background -> {{{LightBlue, White}}},
   ItemDisplayFunction -> (NumberForm[#, {6, 2}] &)};

Dataset[dset, opts]
```

[image]

It's easy to aggregate rows and/or columns:

```
Query[All, <|#, "Total" -> Total[#]|> &] @ dset // Dataset[#, opts] &
```

[image]

```
Query[
   All /* Query[<|#, "Mean" -> Mean[#]|> &],
   <|#, "Mean" -> Mean[#]|> &] @ dset // Dataset[#, opts] &
```

[image]